# How to mock response from function inside arrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, proxyquire

I need to mock the response of a function being called inside an arrow function to test every line of the code. I have the following code:

```js
function foo() {
     return 'apiCall'
}

const handle = async () => {
const a = await foo()

  if (a == 'apiCall') {
    //do something

  } else {
    //do other thing
  }
}

module.exports = {
  foo,
  handle
}
```

I can use the following dev dependencies: chai, chai-http, node-mocks-http, proxyquire, sinon. How can I mock the response of `foo()` to test every line of `handle()` function?